# AKFFTTap only returns array of 0.0

Tags: ios, swift, signal-processing, fft, audiokit

I am attempting to simply take the FFT of a recording: as follows

```
        let originalFile=try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "whiteNoise.wav")
        let originalPlayer=try AKAudioPlayer(file: originalFile)
        let fft = AKFFTTap.init(originalPlayer)
        //I have tried both with and without .init

        print(fft.fftData)
```

Unfortunately, the only thing printed is an array 512 long of 0.0s. I have checked to see if they are actually just really really tiny numbers, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I can play the file so I know for certain that there is data there.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: I'd really need to see more of the implementation. If you can share source on Github, even privately that would really help. It sounds like you're not pulling data through the tap.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I figured out that FFTTap only takes the FFT of a specific point in the file rather than the entire file (which makes sense cause its called FFTTap) In order to take average frequency response of the entire whiteNoise.wav, I am tapping every 1/30 sec, and summing the fftData, then dividing by the number of taps. Is there some type of scaling in the 512 bins? It seems that with each increasing bin, the value of the fftData decreases. This isnt a problem with my loop,even if I tap the whiteNoise in the middle of the signal, there still seems to be a decrease with bins

Comment: Github found here: https://github.com/loganriddick/AKFFTTapTesting